# DataAnnotations: read out the Name property in code

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have decorated the following enum with Display DataAnnotation attributes:

```
public enum RequiredOptions
{
    [Display(Name="Optional",Description ="Optional")]
    Optional,
    [Display(Name="Not Used",Description ="Not Used")]
    NotUsed,
    [Display(Name="Required",Description ="Required")]
    Required
}
```

I'd like to read out the Name value of the Display attribute for a given enum value in my code.  How do I do this?

```
    public static string DisplayRequiredOptionName(RequiredOptions opt)
    {
        // Return the value of Name from the display attribute from opt
    }
```

Comment: I think you'd normally do that with reflection and GetCustomAttributes().

Answer (score 0):

Well, after doing some digging in the MVC source code (see src\System.Web.Mvc\Html\SelectExtensions.cs, see GetDisplayName()), here's what I got to work:

```
    public static string GetEnumDisplayName<T>(T enumInstance)
    {
        return GetDisplayName(enumInstance.GetType().GetField(enumInstance.ToString()));
    }

    private static string GetDisplayName(FieldInfo field)
    {
        DisplayAttribute display = field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(inherit: false);
        if (display != null)
        {
            string name = display.GetName();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                return name;
            }
        }

        return field.Name;
    }
```